# Error when plotting using ggplot2: Error in validate_facets(x) : object 'set' not found

Tags: r, facet-wrap

I want to plot data in R but I keep getting an error related to `facet_grid(-set)` which is: `Error in validate_facets(x) : object 'set' not found`

```r
install.packages('Tmisc')
library(Tmisc)
data(quartet)
View(quartet)

quartet %>%
    group_by(set) %>%
    summarize(mean(x), sd(x), mean(y), sd(y), cor(x,y))
    ggplot(quartet,aes(x,y)) 
        + geom_point() 
        + geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE) 
        + facet_wrap(-set)

> Error in validate_facets(x) : object 'set' not found
```

Comment: even though I'm not completely sure how your data look, have you tried `~set` instead of `-set`?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```r
install.packages('Tmisc')
library(Tmisc)
data(quartet)
View(quartet)

    quartet %>%
        group_by(set) %>%
        summarize(mean(x), sd(x), mean(y), sd(y), cor(x,y)) %>%
        ggplot(quartet,aes(x,y)) 
            + geom_point() 
            + geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE) 
            + facet_wrap(~set)
```

you have to use **tilde not dash in front of set** because set is an independent variable in the quartet dataset. dash is used to remove a column from selection

Answer (score 0):

It works with the code:

```
ggplot(quartet, 
       aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm,
              se=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~set)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the tidyverse package and then this command supposed to be work. since ggplot function is under the tidyverse package

Comment: Please add suggestions like this as a comment, not an answer because you cannot know if it actually helps with the problem.

Comment: While commenting on previous solutions or problems, it must require 50 reputations to make a comment. Which is why I couldn't comment except in reply on my post/suggestion point in this